# Tweet form within an interactive PDF?

Tags: pdf, twitter, pdf-generation, acrobat, tweets

I'm creating an **interactive PDF** file where users will be given a `text field to fill in`, and have that content included in a `partially filled out Tweet`.

**Eg**: I saw my mother with Santa Claus, and I ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**.

Where the first part of the message is always a part of the Tweet, and the text field that fills in a specific part of the status is completely up to the user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a submit button in the pdf that submits the form data to your server. On the server side you collect the form data and post the Tweets.

Comment: I'm trying to do something that would allow the tweet to be sent by them though, instead of me posting them. Or do you mean, taking the form input and adding it to the form on my server, then sending it back?

Comment: I meant for you to post them from the server side. Adobe Acrobat Javascript object model supports communicating with web services but this works only in Adobe Acrobat and not in Adobe Reader as far as I know.